# Flutter: Why Provided data is not available in Drawer widget

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer, provider

I am trying to get the user from a `StreamProvider` that I declared before the `MaterialApp` in a `Drawer` widget, but I get this error:

````
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this NavigationSideBar Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that NavigationSideBar is under your MultiProvider/Provider<User>.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
  ```

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was
NavigationSideBar
lib\…\01-dashboard\dashboard.dart:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf
package:provider/src/provider.dart:269
#1      Provider.of
package:provider/src/provider.dart:221
#2      NavigationSideBar.build

#3      StatelessElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4701
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627
...


This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.
````

The code from `main` looks like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return ErrorWidget(snapshot.hasError);
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return StreamProvider<User>.value(
                value: AuthService().user,
                child: MaterialApp(
                  home: Dashboard(),
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                ));
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
```

In `Dashboard` i have a `Scaffold` widget with a `Drawer`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: NavigationSideBar(),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: DashboardBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And the `NavigationSideBar` looks like this:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context); // HERE appears the error
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Text(
              'Side menu',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green,
              // image: DecorationImage(
              //     fit: BoxFit.fill,
              //     image: AssetImage('assets/images/cover.jpg')),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.input),
            title: Text('Welcome'),
            onTap: () => {},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
            title: Text('Profile'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.border_color),
            title: Text('Feedback'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
          user == null ? Text("Some text") : ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
            title: Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pop()},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I don't see why I get this error, because the `StreamProvider` is **above** the `Drawer` widget. Or maybe I didn't understand well how `StreamProvider` works...

Anyway, my question is how can I access the `Prvider.of<User>` from `Drawer`?

Comment: From these pieces it looks like it should work, could you share the whole widgets

Comment: Sure, i edited the question. And I added the full `error message`